# Scala: How to parse the value of a map type which in turn has multiple and different values for a single key

Tags: scala

My Map type looks like this:
*(home,[9243 Donald Junction,Chicago,75015,WrappedArray(235-147-9030)])*

The data type of the same is as follows:
*MapType(StringType,StructType(StructField(street,StringType,true), StructField(city,StringType,true), StructField(zip_code,IntegerType,true), StructField(phones,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)),true)*

I want to extract each value and put them in a string. I am trying the following code but in this, the ArrayType is also converted to a string and I am unable to extract its value:

---CODE HERE
*from the value of the map, extract the value, use each comma-separated value, if it is an array, take the value out of the array and finally create a comma-separated list of all the values*

````
val mapValues = d.asInstanceOf[Map[StringType, StructType]]
val mapValue = mapValues.values
mapValue.foreach(m =>
  m match {
    case a if a.isInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[String]] =>```
     
---CODE HERE

      ```)
    case _ => allMapValues=allMapValues+" "+m
  }
)
println("VALUES OFF A MAP TYPE: "+allMapValues)```
````

Comment: Using cast/`asInstanceOf` and `Any` are symptom of bad design and/or misunderstanding about the type safety

Comment: Your design won't work because `isInstanceOf[WrappedArray[String]]` is a run-time evaluation, after type erasure has taken place. So that `case` will always fail and go to the `_` default.

Comment: Using `Any` is not "secondary", it is the primary reason for the problems with this code. Once you fix the use of `Any` the code will be much easier to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example of your schema like:

```
val example_Rows = Seq(Row(Map("id" -> Row("Gran Via", "Madrid", 28000, Array("913000000", "913000001")))))

val schema =
  StructType(
    List(StructField("map",
      MapType(StringType,
        StructType(List(
          StructField("street", StringType, true),
          StructField("city", StringType, true),
          StructField("zip_code", IntegerType, true),
          StructField("phones", ArrayType(StringType, true), true)))))))
/*
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|map                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|[id -> [Gran Via, Madrid, 28000, [913000000, 913000001]]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
*/
```

You can extract the values of your map with the function **map_values**, and flatten the nested types using the **flattenStructSchema**(from https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-flatten-nested-struct-column/) :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{ map_values, col, concat_ws}

def flattenStructSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
    val columnName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

    f.dataType match {
      case st: StructType => flattenStructSchema(st, columnName)
      case _ => Array(col(columnName).as(columnName.replace(".","_")))
    }
  })
}
```

The schemas of your values are:

```
val values_schema = StructType(List(
  StructField("street", StringType, true),
  StructField("city", StringType, true),
  StructField("zip_code", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("phones", ArrayType(StringType, true), true)))

val column_value_schema = StructType(List(StructField("map_value", values_schema)))
```

Doing the concat columns you have all data in a string:

```
val df0 = df.withColumn("map_value", map_values($"map")(0))
    .select(flattenStructSchema(column_value_schema):_*)

df0.withColumn("str", concat_ws(",", df0.schema.fieldNames.map(col(_)): _*)).select("str").show(false)
```

gives the result in the str field:

```
/*
+-----------------------------------------+
|str                                      |
+-----------------------------------------+
|Gran Via,Madrid,28000,913000000,913000001|
+-----------------------------------------+
*/
```